# Change column to row - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
u_a_id      user_id       c_nm       c_val     c_seq
1           10012         test1      123       1
1           10012         test2      abc       2
1           10012         test3      xyz       3
1           10012         test4      123       4

2           10013         test1      456       1
2           10013         test2      xvv       2
2           10013         test3      tau       3
2           10013         test4      uyt       4
```

I need to convert `user_id` to a row format for each `u_a_id` with `c_seq` = 100

Output:

```
u_a_id      user_id       c_nm       c_val     c_seq
1           10012         test1      123       1
1           10012         test2      abc       2
1           10012         test3      xyz       3
1           10012         test4      123       4
1           10012         user_id    10012     100

2           10013         test1      456       1
2           10013         test2      xvv       2
2           10013         test3      tau       3
2           10013         test4      uyt       4
2           10013         user_id    10013     100
```

How to do it using Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not `union all`?

```
select u_a_id, user_id, c_nm, c_val, c_seq from table1
union all
select distinct u_a_id, user_id, 'user_id', to_char(user_id), 100 from table1
order by u_a_id, c_seq
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67e4bc631a5ab383f48e27d721967980)</sup>**

Comment: Didn't get the requirement, what is c_seq=100, is it static for all?
and why c_val and user_id has duplicate data? provide some more example of output.